# How do I get unique attribute values of an array of objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-5, unique

I'm using RoR 5.  How do I select unique attribute values from an array of objects?  I've tried

```
attr_values = my_objects.uniq{|r| r.attr_name}
```

But "attr_values" is an array of objects of the same type that "my_objects" consists of.  I want the array to be objects of the type of "r.attr_name."

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and expected output? If this is a collection of records from the database you can use `.distinct` or grouping instead which avoids loading a huge amount of records from the DB.

Comment: How about my_objects.pluck(:attr_name).uniq

Comment: @bkunzi01 using `my_objects.pluck('DISTINCT attr_name')` could be better than pulling all the data out in the first place.

Comment: @max: provided that `my_objects` is an AR relation and not an array, as the name (and question text) suggest.

Comment: I'm guessing `attr_values = my_objects.map(&:attr_name).uniq` is what he is looking for but its a really fuzzy question. @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Read the comments too late, but @max has it right. You can combine `.distinct` and `.pluck` without the SQL segment, see my answer. @bkunzi01, your solution creates a big array, only to remove duplicates later, it won't be performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear on your post, but if that "array" is instead an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, you could do `.distinct.pluck(:attr_name)`, for example: `User.distinct.pluck(:role)` => `SELECT DISTINCT "users"."role" FROM "users"`

If it's actually an array (`my_objects.is_a? Array`), the solution is `my_objects.map(&:attr_name).uniq`.